# ng test fails on reload/file change

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-cli

When running `ng test` in my angular-cli generated project the initial test runs just fine. However, if I change a file, any file, and the tests re-run they fail with the error

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (D:\Developer\project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:14022:109)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (D:\Developer\project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13961:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (D:\Developer\project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13873:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (D:\Developer\project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13712:29)
    at new TypeScriptFileRefactor (D:\Developer\project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\refactor.js:79:35)
    at Object.findLazyRoutes (D:\Developer\project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\lazy_routes.js:18:22)
    at AotPlugin._findLazyRoutesInAst (D:\Developer\project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:216:50)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (D:\Developer\project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:494:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

I've tried resetting my sourcemaps by running `ng test -sm=false` also because that's fixed similar errors in the past.

```
> ng -v

Angular CLI: 1.7.1
Node: 6.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 4.4.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cli: 1.7.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.4.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.4.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.1
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.7.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9588 ?